# start simple 1-producer 2-consumers through executor service

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, producer-consumer

```
public class SemActionPlace {

    public SemMonitor StartConsumerProducer() {
        SemMonitor monitor = new SemMonitor();
        List<Thread> threads = new LinkedList<>();
        Thread p1 = new Thread(new Producer(monitor), "P1");
        p1.start();
        Thread c1 = new Thread(new Consumer(monitor), "C-odd");
        c1.start();
        Thread c2 = new Thread(new Consumer(monitor), "C-even");
        c2.start();
        threads.add(p1);
        threads.add(c1);
        threads.add(c2);
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return monitor;
    }
}
```

the code work just fine when I start thread through start() - join(), however, I failed to find mistake when I try to do the same through the executor service. It's important for me to save names of the threads and mutual monitor. Please, tell me how can I execute the threads through the executor service ?

The piece of code below doen't work properly. Where is mistake ?

```
public SemMonitor StartConsumerProducer() {
    SemMonitor monitor = new SemMonitor();
    Thread p1 = new Thread(new Producer(monitor), "P1");
    Thread c1 = new Thread(new Consumer(monitor), "C-odd");
    Thread c2 = new Thread(new Consumer(monitor), "C-even");
    ThreadPoolExecutor service = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    service.execute(p1);
    service.execute(c1);
    service.execute(c2);
    System.out.println(service.getCompletedTaskCount());
    System.out.println(service.getCompletedTaskCount());
    return monitor;
}
```

I need one simple thing from the executor server is that I wanna that it works like simple start() - join() solution works ( first piece of code ) .

```
class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private final SemMonitor monitor;

    Consumer(SemMonitor monitor) {
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = t + 1000;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
            consoleLog(monitor.activeThreadName,false);
            if (/*monitor.semaphore.tryAcquire() && */monitor.activeThreadName.equals( Thread.currentThread().getName())) {

                try {
                    consoleLog(String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " was notified "),monitor.enableLog);
                    monitor.semaphore.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                monitor.get(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
            try{
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
class Producer implements Runnable {

    private SemMonitor monitor;

    Producer(SemMonitor monitor) {
        this.monitor = monitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String threadNameToWork;
        Integer randNum;
        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long end = t + 500;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
            if (monitor.semaphore.tryAcquire()) {
                randNum = ((Number) (random() * 100)).intValue();
                if (randNum % 2 == 0) {
                    threadNameToWork = "C-even";
                } else {
                    threadNameToWork = "C-odd";
                }
                try {
                    monitor.putItem(randNum, Thread.currentThread().getName(), threadNameToWork);
                    Thread.sleep(3);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class Monitor {

    private double currItem;
    private boolean isConsumersShouldWaitProducer = true;
    private boolean isConsuming = false;
    private String threadNameToWork;

    synchronized void putRandNumber(double producerOutput, String producerName, String threadNameToWork) {
        if (isConsumersShouldWaitProducer) {
            System.out.println("Consumers wait for new Production");
        }
        this.threadNameToWork = threadNameToWork;
        currItem = producerOutput;
        System.out.println("Producer " + producerName + " putRandNumber Item: " + currItem);
        if (currItem > 3) {
            notifyAll();
            isConsumersShouldWaitProducer = false;
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized void consumeRandNumber(String threadName) {
        if (isConsumersShouldWaitProducer) {
            try {
                this.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Caught Interrupted Exception while waiting to consume currItem: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if (isConsuming) {
            try {
                this.wait();
                isConsuming = true;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Caught Interrupted Exception while waiting to consume currItem: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        switch (Thread.currentThread().getName()) {
        /*switch (threadNameToWork) {*/
            case "C-odd":
                isConsuming = true;
                if (currItem % 2 != 0 && threadNameToWork.equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())) {
                    consumeItems(threadName);
                }
                isConsuming = false;
                notifyAll();
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case "C-even":
                isConsuming = true;
                if (currItem % 2 == 0 && threadNameToWork.equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())) {
                    consumeItems(threadName);
                }
                isConsuming = false;
                notifyAll();
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private synchronized void consumeItems(String threadName) {
        isConsumersShouldWaitProducer = true;
        String randNumType = "*odd/even*";
        System.out.println("Consumer:" + threadName + " consumed " + randNumType + " Items = " + currItem);
        notifyAll();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about telling us what "doesn't work properly" means.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I mean executor service doen't work in the same way as simple thread start() - join() methods work

Comment: Uh, yeah. So **how** doesn't it work the same way?

Comment: Okey. During one second the producer generates random number if number is odd the thread with name "C-odd" consumes the number, if number is even threa with name "C-even" consumes the number. When the second is over,  I return monitor with data member that contains log what thread consume what number. At the end, send this log to the unit test. The end.

Comment: Thread pool executors don't execute threads. Instead, they execute tasks, either `Runnable` or `Callable`. So you don't have to create the threads, that is automatically done for you inside the executor. You also need to shutdown the executor and wait until all tasks are completed.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Thread implements Runnable interface, so in theory, it is validated for JVM

Comment: Amazing how you've still managed to avoid telling how the code with executor is behaving differently from the code with start/join. Third time's the charm? And yea, it would be cleaner to use `Runnable` and not `Thread` for the executor.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yeah, thx for attention. However, my business logic depend on the name of the threads could you at least tell me how can I create three thread through executor service with unique names like I need ?

Comment: Relying on a thread name is really bad design. You could do an ugly hack with a `ThreadFactory`, but the best way would be to fix your design.

Comment: @Kayaman I was about to say exactly the same.

Comment: @Kayaman It just doen't do what I need. For example,  the first piece of code return to my 79 - 85 logs ( number plus the name of thread that handle it ) the second piece of code return to me 0 logs. I cannot debug into executor service ( probably should have IDEA Ultimate Edition IDE ) , I don't know the undercover problem.

Comment: @Kayaman how the ugly hask with ThreadFactory will be look like ? It just play exercise. I've much time to redesign the solution.  Could you give me a clue ? Cause I saw only example with single thread ... but how to put 3 threads to ThreadFactory and then put the factory into executor service ???

Comment: @Yang True, `Thread` implements `Runnable`. However, there's no need to create extra threads, which are not precisely cheap.

Comment: @BernardCasey Please post the code of `Consumer` and `Producer`, along with the output, and clearly explain the expected results vs the actual results.

Comment: Too ugly to bother really. Besides, it sounds like you don't really need to care about the thread's name. If you're using it for logging, you could give a name to your `Consumer` and `Producer` classes instead.

Comment: @Kayaman but I have 2 consumer ... So if you mean use Class name for business logic reaction it probably doen't help

Comment: I didn't suggest to rename classes, that would be even worse than what you have now. Or go for Yang's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something with Thread name right? The thread name you created in using new Thread will not pass into `ExecutorService`, but this will

```
ThreadFactory namedThreadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
                                       .setNameFormat("thread-%d").build()
```

Then

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(namedThreadFactory);
```

Now you have thread with name as `thread-1`, `thread-2`

OR set thread name in your run() method

```
Thread.currentThread().setName(myName)
```

---

To make sure your thread is finished, add this before you return the monitor,

```
service.shutdown();
while (!service.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
   log.info("Awaiting completion of threads.");
}
```

Comment: unfortunately didn't help

Comment: yeah, but how should I know what thread will be producer ( thread-1 ; thread- 2 or thread - 3 ) and which two will be consumers ? I believe the should be the better way for naming ... May there is the way to rename the threads after we create Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3) ???

Comment: @BernardCasey edited `Thread.currentThread().setName(myName)`

Comment: So I probably need some kind of switch case for renaming in monitor class ... yeah  ?

Comment: @BernardCasey There are many ways to pass name into `run()` method, one option is that you can create` Public void setMyThreadName(myName){ this.myName = myName;}` method which save `myName` as an instance variable in your `Producer`, then in your `run()` method, just use` Thread.currentThread().setName(this.myName)`